# XSLT Custom sorting - not sorting as expected

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am trying to use a custom order to sort some xml that starts off in the following structure by the **REGION** element.

```
<EXPORT>
    <ESTABLISHMENTS>
        <ESTABLISHMENT>
            <NAME>One</NAME>
            <LOCATION>
                <REGION>BERKSHIRE</REGION>
                <COUNTRY>England</COUNTRY>
            </LOCATION>
        </ESTABLISHMENT>
        <ESTABLISHMENT>
            <NAME>Two</NAME>
            <LOCATION>
                <REGION>DERBYSHIRE</REGION>
                <COUNTRY>England</COUNTRY>
            </LOCATION>
        </ESTABLISHMENT>
        <ESTABLISHMENT>
            <NAME>Three</NAME>
            <LOCATION>
                <REGION>BRISTOL</REGION>
                <COUNTRY>England</COUNTRY>
            </LOCATION>
        </ESTABLISHMENT>
        <ESTABLISHMENT>
            <NAME>Four</NAME>
            <LOCATION>
                <REGION>CORNWALL &amp; ISLES OF SCILLY</REGION>
                <COUNTRY>England</COUNTRY>
            </LOCATION>
        </ESTABLISHMENT>
        <ESTABLISHMENT>
            <NAME>Five</NAME>
            <LOCATION>
                <REGION>BEDFORDSHIRE</REGION>
                <COUNTRY>England</COUNTRY>
            </LOCATION>
        </ESTABLISHMENT>
    </ESTABLISHMENTS>
</EXPORT>
```

However, when using the following code while those Regions that start with B do appear in the correct order Derbyshire and Cornwall are completely thrown out.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <!-- Declare variables for text case conversion -->
    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="space" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="underscore" select="'_'"/>

    <!-- Genertate key for sorting by region -->
    <xsl:key name="establishment-by-region" match="ESTABLISHMENTS/ESTABLISHMENT/LOCATION" use="REGION"/>
    <!-- Generate key for sorting by Locality -->
    <xsl:key name="establishment-by-locality" match="ESTABLISHMENTS/ESTABLISHMENT/LOCATION" use="LOCALITY"/>

    <!-- England Counties sort order -->
    <xsl:variable name="englandSortOrder">|BEDFORDSHIRE|BERKSHIRE|BRISTOL|BUCKINGHAMSHIRE|CAMBRIDGESHIRE|CHESHIRE|CORNWALL &amp; ISLES OF SCILLY|CUMBRIA|DERBYSHIRE|DEVON|DORSET|COUNTY DURHAM|ESSEX|GLOUCESTERSHIRE|GREATER MANCHESTER|HAMPSHIRE|HEREFORDSHIRE|HERTFORDSHIRE|ISLE OF WIGHT|KENT|LANCASHIRE|LEICESTERSHIRE|LINCOLNSHIRE|LONDON POSTAL DISTRICTS|GREATER LONDON|MERSEYSIDE|NORFOLK|NORTHAMPTONSHIRE|NORTHUMBERLAND|NOTTINGHAMSHIRE|OXFORDSHIRE|RUTLAND|SHROPSHIRE|SOMERSET|STAFFORDSHIRE|SUFFOLK|SURREY|EAST SUSSEX |WEST SUSSEX|TYNE &amp; WEAR|WARWICKSHIRE|WEST MIDLANDS|WILTSHIRE|WORCESTERSHIRE|EAST RIDING OF YORKSHIRE|NORTH YORKSHIRE|SOUTH YORKSHIRE|WEST YORKSHIRE|GUERNSEY|HERM|JERSEY|SARK|ISLE OF MAN|ABERDEEN|ABERDEENSHIRE|ANGUS|ARGYLL &amp; BUTE|NORTH AYRSHIRE|SOUTH AYRSHIRE|DUMFRIES &amp; GALLOWAY|WEST DUNBARTONSHIRE|EDINBURGH|FIFE|GLASGOW|HIGHLAND|INVERCLYDE|NORTH LANARKSHIRE|SOUTH LANARKSHIRE|EAST LOTHIAN|WEST LOTHIAN|MIDLOTHIAN|MORAY|PERTH &amp; KINROSS|SCOTTISH BORDERS|STIRLING|WESTERN ISLES|ISLE OF ANGLESEY|BLAENAU GWENT|BRIDGEND|CAERPHILLY|CARDIFF|CARMARTHENSHIRE|CEREDIGION|CONWY|DENBIGHSHIRE|FLINTSHIRE|GWYNEDD|MERTHYR TYDFIL|MONMOUTHSHIRE|NEATH PORT TALBOT|PEMBROKESHIRE|POWYS|SWANSEA|TORFAEN|VALE OF GLAMORGAN|WREXHAM|COUNTY ANTRIM|COUNTY ARMAGH|BELFAST|COUNTY DOWN|COUNTY FERMANAGH|COUNTY LONDONDERRY|COUNTY CARLOW|COUNTY CAVAN|COUNTY CLARE|COUNTY CORK|COUNTY DONEGAL|DUBLIN|COUNTY GALWAY|COUNTY KERRY|COUNTY KILDARE|COUNTY KILKENNY|COUNTY LAOIS|COUNTY LIMERICK|COUNTY LOUTH|COUNTY MAYO|COUNTY MEATH|COUNTY MONAGHAN|COUNTY ROSCOMMON|COUNTY SLIGO|COUNTY TIPPERARY|COUNTY TYRONE|COUNTY WATERFORD|COUNTY WEXFORD|COUNTY WICKLOW|</xsl:variable>

    <!-- Base template for matching SEER root element -->
    <xsl:template match="EXPORT">
        <xsl:element name="Root">
            <xsl:element name="Story">
                <!-- Loop through all the Regions (Counties) and sort basedon bespke order -->
                <xsl:for-each select="ESTABLISHMENTS/ESTABLISHMENT/LOCATION[count(.| key('establishment-by-region', REGION)[1]) = 1]">
                    <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($englandSortOrder, concat('|', REGION,'|')))" data-type="text"/>

                    <!-- COUNTRY SELECTOR START-->
                    <xsl:if test="COUNTRY = 'England'">
                    <!-- COUNTRY SELECTOR END -->

                    <xsl:element name="print_region_{COUNTRY}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="REGION"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('establishment-by-region', REGION)">
                        <xsl:sort select="LOCALITY"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select='ancestor::ESTABLISHMENT' mode='localities'/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Sort a given region by Locality (Town) -->
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="localities">
        <xsl:for-each select="LOCATION[count(.| key('establishment-by-locality', LOCALITY)[1]) = 1]">

                <xsl:element name="print_location_{COUNTRY}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="LOCALITY"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The results I'm getting from this transformation are as follows which is not really what I was hoping for as Derbyshire appears to not want to move. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
<Root>
<Story>
  <print_region_England>BEDFORDSHIRE</print_region_England>

  <print_region_England>DERBYSHIRE</print_region_England>

  <print_region_England>BERKSHIRE</print_region_England>

  <print_region_England>BRISTOL</print_region_England>

  <print_region_England>CORNWALL &amp; ISLES OF SCILLY</print_region_England>

</Story>
</Root>
```

**NB:** The actual XML includes more variations of **REGION** that necessitate the custom sort but the short version above highlights my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort key explicitly has `data-type="text"` (which is also the default).  You are therefore performing a lexicographic sort on the string values of your sort keys, but you seem to intend to perform a numeric sort.  A numeric sort would require the sort key to be declared with `data-type="number"`.

Comment: If ever there was an example of not being able to see the wood for the trees. Thank you much appreciated.